# C# : Using statement and this keyword

Tags: c#, this, using

While wanting to use using statement, I came across a scenario that I don't understand :

```
private void RoomMealHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MealRoomPlanning fMealRoomPlanning = new MealRoomPlanning(true);
        fMealRoomPlanning .MdiParent = this;
        fMealRoomPlanning.Show(); 
    }
```

This code works correctly and my window is a MdiChild.

However, the following code does not work :

```
private void RoomMealHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MealRoomPlanning fMealRoomPlanning = new MealRoomPlanning(true))
        {
            MdiParent = this;
            fMealRoomPlanning.Show();
        }
    }
```

ArgumentException: 'A form cannot be an MDI child and an MDI parent at the same time.

I also tried to replace this with this.ParentForm doesn't work anymore.

Is there a problem with the scope of this?

Comment: Should not it be `fMealRoomPlanning.MdiParent = this;` in second case also?

Comment: there is an implicit `this` before `MdiParent`. like this: `this.MdiParent = this;`

Comment: You seem to be confusing what `using` is for.  It basically creates a `try-finally` that will make sure the object in the `using` is disposed at the end of the scope.  What you seem to want is call "object initializer" and it's format is `new Thing(){ Prop = value, OtherProp = value,};`

Comment: you could also extend the constructor of `MealRoomPlanning` to pass an optional MDIParent inside it. then you could use the using block, get automatically rid of the control as soon as it will be closed and have your code consise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have just understood that Using is not necessary for non-modal Form.

> When a non modal form is closed, the Dispose will automatically be called by WinForms.

Unlike Forms opened with ShowDialog for which the Dispose is not called automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In your first snippet, you set the MdiParent-Property of fMealRoomPlanning.

In your second snippet, you set MdiParent of your own class instance (`this.MdiParent`).

You should set it on the object you are using:

```
private void RoomMealHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MealRoomPlanning fMealRoomPlanning = new MealRoomPlanning(true))
        {
            fMealRoomPlanning.MdiParent = this;
            fMealRoomPlanning.Show();
        }
    }
```

That's why many style-checks recommend using the `this`-Qualifier although it is redundant. This makes it more clear if you set a local, global or class variable.

Comment: Yap I also think the OP is confusing `using` with the `With` keyword from VB.

Comment: I've tried that doesn't work either. The window opens and closes as if Dispose() came directly after the Show(). With ShowDialog() it works, but like a modal window.

Comment: That's exactly what a using-block is supposed to do - dispose the used object after the block finished its execution. If you don't want this behavior, don't use a using-block.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `MdiParent = this` to `fMealRoomPlanning.MdiParent = this`

Answer (score -2):

Try Changing the 2nd Code, After creating **object** for **MealRoomPlanning** class
change **MdiParent = this;**    to  **fMealRoomPlanning.MdiParent = this;**

```
private void RoomMealHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MealRoomPlanning fMealRoomPlanning = new MealRoomPlanning(true))
    {
        fMealRoomPlanning.MdiParent = this;
        fMealRoomPlanning.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this answer different from the answer by [Computerfreak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036106/5174469) ? beside that it is missing the explanation that @Computerfreak has provided

Comment: @MongZhu, if you look on answered time You will notice that the time difference between [Compufreak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036106/13851956) and [Naveen Dogga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036772/13851956) or [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036113/13851956) answers is rather small. We posted our answers, not knowing that the answer has already been given.

Comment: @catman0745 have a look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63036019/timeline) this answer here was posted 20 minutes later than the ones by you and by Compufreak. I watched it appear here. Otherwise I would not have written my comment. 20 Minutes should be enough to see the already posted answers.